# Need help in unix find with xargs command

Tags: unix, xargs

Am trying to delete files with below find command, few files are not deleting and all those file names are like: filname.123.log.

I can't rename or can't do any thing on file name just need to delete 
command

```
$ find /BASE/CODE/LOGS_BACK -type f -mtime +60 | xargs rm -f
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

I googled and try with the below command but it is giving different error.

```
$ find /BASE/CODE/LOGS_BACK -type f -mtime +60 | xargs -0 rm -f
xargs: argument line too long
```

Can you please help regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

using -0 option in xargs means using -print0 option in find :

find /BASE/CODE/LOGS_BACK -type f -mtime +60 **-print0** | xargs **-0** rm -f

Then all results of find will be ended with '\0' NUL char and xargs will regenerate list correctly by parsing with same char.

Answer (score 0):

`find` can directly execute a command for each result:

```
$ find /BASE/CODE/LOGS_BACK -type f -mtime +60 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

`{}` is replaced with each matching filename.  `\;` end the command.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest way to achieve what you want:

```
find /BASE/CODE/LOGS_BACK -type f -mtime +60 -exec rm -f {} +
```

Note the ending `+` which does the same job as `xargs`.